# TypeOf and CType code equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can someone help me the equivalent code to C#

```
Public Sub ClearTextBox(ByVal root As Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In root.Controls
        ClearTextBox(ctrl)
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: How did the online converters fail you?

Answer (score 3):

```
public void ClearTextBox(Control root)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in root.Controls)
    {
        ClearTextBox(ctrl);
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            ctrl.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Comment: Try `((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;` instead.

Comment: sorry for that mistake